# sort json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

For example with have this code:

```
var json = {
    "user1" : {
        "id" : 3
    },
    "user2" : {
        "id" : 6
    },
    "user3" : {
        "id" : 1
    }
}
```

How can I sort this json to be like this -

```
var json = {
    "user3" : {
        "id" : 1
    },
    "user1" : {
        "id" : 3
    },
    "user2" : {
        "id" : 6
    }
}
```

I sorted the users with the IDs..

I don't know how to do this in javascript..

Comment: exact duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value). Notice that you cannot sort them; objects are *unordered* key-value maps.

Comment: it's not helping me.. i have different json..and the answer there doesn't work on my json for some reason..

Comment: Of course you need to adapt it… Did you understand how it works? If so and you had problems at adapting it, then please post your attempt.

Comment: Convert the JSON to an array, sort the array, then convert back to JSON. Should work, but maybe you don't need to use JSON if you want to do this.

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood: There's no JSON involved, he's got plain object literals. And converting it back to an object will invalidate the sorting, so there's no point in doing it.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

First off, that's **not** JSON.  It's a JavaScript object literal.  JSON is a *string representation* of data, that just so happens to very closely resemble JavaScript syntax.

Second, you have an object.  They are unsorted.  The order of the elements cannot be guaranteed.  If you want guaranteed order, you *need* to use an array.  This will require you to change your data structure.

One option might be to make your data look like this:

```
var json = [{
    "name": "user1",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "name": "user2",
    "id": 6
}, {
    "name": "user3",
    "id": 1
}];
```

Now you have an array of objects, and we can sort it.

```
json.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

The resulting array will look like:

```
[{
    "name": "user3",
    "id" : 1
}, {
    "name": "user1",
    "id" : 3
}, {
    "name": "user2",
    "id" : 6
}];
```

Comment: Excellent answer and to make a reverse order : `return b.id - a.id;`

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simple snippet that sorts a javascript representation of a Json.

```
function isObject(v) {
    return '[object Object]' === Object.prototype.toString.call(v);
};

JSON.sort = function(o) {
if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.sort().map(JSON.sort);
    } else if (isObject(o)) {
        return Object
            .keys(o)
        .sort()
            .reduce(function(a, k) {
                a[k] = JSON.sort(o[k]);

                return a;
            }, {});
    }

    return o;
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```
JSON.sort({
    c: {
        c3: null,
        c1: undefined,
        c2: [3, 2, 1, 0],
    },
    a: 0,
    b: 'Fun'
});
```

That will output:

```
{
  a: 0,
  b: 'Fun',
  c: {
    c2: [3, 2, 1, 0],
    c3: null
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is interesting, it does not directly address the question posed.

Comment: I think, it answers it with a little bit of interpretation. You can sort whatever you want with that and don't have to provide an array. The interesting part is Object.keys( ... ).sort( ... ).

Comment: The answer of this specific question should be : 
`const sortedJson = Object.keys(json).sort( (a,b) => json[a].id - json[b].id ).reduce( (accu, val, index, array) => {
        accu[\`${val}\`] = json[val];
        return accu;
    }, {});`

Answer (score 1):

In some ways, your question seems very legitimate, but I still might label it an `XY problem`. I'm guessing the end result is that you want to *display* the sorted values in some way? As Bergi said in the comments, you can never quite *rely* on Javascript objects ( `{i_am: "an_object"}` ) to show their properties in any particular order.

For the displaying order, I might suggest you take each key of the object (ie, `i_am`) and sort them into an ordered array. Then, use that array when retrieving elements of your object to display. Pseudocode:

```
var keys = [...]
var sortedKeys = [...]
for (var i = 0; i < sortedKeys.length; i++) {
  var key = sortedKeys[i];
  addObjectToTable(json[key]);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
if(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(pcOrGroup).sort()) === JSON.stringify(Object.keys(orGroup)).sort())
{
    return true;
}
```