# Sort a Javascript options value alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have something similar to the following object below:

`EUR: {
    name: 'Europe',
    countries: {
       FR: {
          name: 'France',
          cities: {}
       },
       DE: {
          name: 'Germany',
          cities: {}
       },
       ES: {
          name: 'Spain',
          cities: {}
       }
    }
 }`

I am trying to figure out a way to sort countries in alphabetical order on countries then the name of each country e.g France, Spain, Germany. The approach I was going to take was splitting this out into an array First and rebuilding.

I was wondering if anybody has any different approaches that I am missing they could help me with?

Comment: you miss an (or more) array/s for sorting. objects have actually no order.

Comment: If order really matters to you, use an array. Javascript objects properties don't really have order.

Comment: Ans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: When you split them out to arrays and sort, you'd need to keep the arrays, if for no other reason than to have a way to access the objects in order. You can keep the object structure too, but there will never be any reliable ordering.

Comment: Yes, `countries` should probably be defined as `countries: [ {FR: { name: 'France' ...` Then I would use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) to do the sorting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort json object in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript)

Comment: As other had pointed out, The order of the elements cannot be guaranteed for object property.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this in the past to bring some order to an object:

```
EUR: {
    name: 'Europe',
    countries: {
       FR: {
          name: 'France',
          cities: {}
       },
       DE: {
          name: 'Germany',
          cities: {}
       },
       ES: {
          name: 'Spain',
          cities: {}
       },
       order : ['DE', 'ES', 'FR']
    }
 }
```

Each object would receive an `order` key, which is an array of the keys for that object. Then when you iterate over the object, you can keep the order using the `order` key. The downside is that you not only need to maintain the object (add, update, remove) but also the `order` key as well.

Though I'd highly recommend actually making an array of objects instead of nesting the objects, since object keys have no order.

```
 EUR: {
    name: 'Europe',
    countries: [{
          name: 'France',
          abbr: 'FR',
          cities: {}
       },{
          name: 'Germany',
          abbr: 'DE',
          cities: {}
       },{
          name: 'Spain',
          abbr: 'ES',
          cities: {}
       }]
 }
```

Then you could iterate through the `EUR.countries` array, and sort by either the `.name` key or the `.abbr` key.

EDIT: I should probably actually show the iteration to sort them, right?

```
var sorted = EUR.countries.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase();
});
```

I make the names lowercase because the sort function works with Unicode. If it sorts in the wrong order, just flip the sign.