# Sort json data by comparing two objects

Tags: jquery, json

Please help! I have the following json data below and I want to compare the object's Date and Request using jquery and return the data with the recent date and latest request.

json:

```
[Object{
 'Date': '3/27/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '2'
},
Object{
 'Date': '3/28/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '1'
},
Object{
 'Date': '3/27/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '1'
},
Object{
 'Date': '3/28/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '2'
}]
```

So the expected result would be:

```
[Object{
 'Date': '3/28/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '2'
 },
 Object{
 'Date': '3/28/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '1'
 },
 Object{
 'Date': '3/27/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '2'
 },
Object{
'Date': '3/27/2017',
'Item': '100',
'Request': '1'
}]
```

Comment: i don't think you need jquery for this. Use javascript sort() method.

Comment: this is not json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort json object in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This link will give you some idea how to work sort javascript object.

[Sort Json object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript)

[Simple function to sort an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175093/simple-function-to-sort-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: it would compare two elements, not just one.

Comment: From those link you can get some ideas how to do that and if you try yourself I guess you can solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
var json = [{
    'Date': '3/27/2017',
    'Item': '100',
    'Request': '2'
  },
  {
    'Date': '3/28/2017',
    'Item': '100',
    'Request': '1'
  },
  {
    'Date': '3/27/2017',
    'Item': '100',
    'Request': '1'
  },
  {
    'Date': '3/28/2017',
    'Item': '100',
    'Request': '2'
  }
];

// sort function callback
function sort_obj(a, b) {
  return (new Date(b.Date) > new Date(a.Date) ||
            b.Request > a.Request) ? 1 : -1;
}
var output = [];
output.push($(json).sort(sort_obj));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `jquery` for to perform the sorting operation. You can overcome by using plain `Javascript` code.

(This is [the source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) you need to read)

Also I've added code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59jwd0c8/12/)

And also the code snippet below can be run.

Note: `return (b.Date - a.Date)` sorts the objects from the object that has the biggest date to the object that has the smallest date. 
`return (a.Date - b.Date)` sorts from small to big. 
This is valid for the all elements of an array (`return a-b` and `return b-a`)

Good luck!

```js
let array = [{
 'Date': '3/27/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '2'
},
{
 'Date': '3/28/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '1'
},
{
 'Date': '3/27/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '1'
},
{
 'Date': '3/28/2017',
 'Item': '100',
 'Request': '2'
}]

array.sort(compare)

function compare (a, b) {
 return (new Date(b.Date) - new Date(a.Date))
}

console.log(array)
```