# How to reposition JSON structure key and value?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json like this:

```
[
    {
        "tipe": "foo1",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 1,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo2",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 2,
        "hasil": 1
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo3",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 3,
        "hasil": 0
    }
]
```

I want to reposition the structure of json in case `hasil = 1` into last position, and keep the seq value,

I've reasearch before asking here, unfortunately I don't know the right keyword of this issue.

purpose:

```
[
    {
        "tipe": "foo1",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 1,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo3",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 2,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo2",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 3,
        "hasil": 1
    }
]
```

there's a way to make it possible?

Comment: sorting an array. It is what you need.

Comment: This question seemingly has nothing to do with JSON at all...

Comment: Try to check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) your array with user function

```js
var array = [
    {
        "tipe": "foo1",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 1,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo2",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 2,
        "hasil": 1
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo3",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 3,
        "hasil": 0
    }
];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.hasil - b.hasil;
});

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].seq = i+1;
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: OP is looking to retain the `seq` value at the same index.

Comment: the problem is about seq, i need to keep seq in the same position as first json,

Comment: @flix Check update. After sort re-iterate your array and re-assign seq

Comment: @flix Can you verify if your original `seq` value will always be in order and not loose any value (like 1,2,4,5,7) in between?

Comment: @gurvinder372 for real, i have 6 index of json, and this `seq` is like a ranking, though the answer is right, ill try it first

Answer (score 1):

Sort your array by `hasil` then loop through it to reassign `seq`:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "tipe": "foo1",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 1,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo2",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 2,
        "hasil": 1
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo3",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 3,
        "hasil": 0
    }
];
   
var seqs = arr.map(e => e.seq);
arr.sort((a, b) => a.hasil - b.hasil).forEach((e, i) => e.seq = seqs[i]);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: OP is looking to retain the seq value at the same index

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of `hasil` values and sort it and using `array#map` and `object#assign` create your new array.

```js
var input = [{ "tipe": "foo1", "color": "red", "size": 92, "seq": 1, "hasil": 0 }, { "tipe": "foo2", "color": "red", "size": 92, "seq": 2, "hasil": 1 }, { "tipe": "foo3", "color": "red", "size": 92, "seq": 3, "hasil": 0 }],
    sortedHasil = input.map(({hasil}) => hasil).sort(),
    result = input.map((o, i) => Object.assign(o, {'hasil': sortedHasil[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try sort function 
if u dont want to sort u can do it with if else

```
var input =[
    {
        "tipe": "foo1",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 1,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo3",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 2,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo2",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 3,
        "hasil": 1
    }
]

input.sort(function (a,b){

    return a.hasil - b.hasil


})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a sort and then a map function to handle this, like

```js
var json = [
    {
        "tipe": "foo1",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 1,
        "hasil": 0
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo2",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 2,
        "hasil": 1
    },
    {
        "tipe": "foo3",
        "color": "red",
        "size": 92,
        "seq": 3,
        "hasil": 0
    }
]


var newArr = json.sort(function(a, b){
  if(a.hasil === b.hasil)
      return a.seq  - b.seq;

  return a.hasil - b.hasil
}).map(function(a, i) {
  return {
    ...a,
    seq: i+1
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```