# Format JSON in descending order

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

In the below json file i want to sort in descending order the content within docs field. There are two blocks . The data is dynamic meaning there can be multiple blocks-- it can be 5, it can be 10 such block within docs.

```
{
"Scoring":1.68466776,
"_text_":[
],
"id":"health_analytics.pdf",
"jac_Score":0.07370184254606366,
"matchScore":0.65,
"scaledTf_idf":0.0,
"searchTerm":[
"Machine learning",
"Deep learning",
"R",
"Python",
"Sas"
],
"sortingScore":59.78
}
```

and,

```
{
    "Scoring":2.029842275,
    "_text_":[
    ],
    "id":"customer_channel_analytics_bang.pdf",
    "jac_Score":0.09041591320072333,
    "matchScore":0.6875,
    "scaledTf_idf":0.0,
    "searchTerm":[
    "Machine learning",
    "Deep learning",
    "Sas",
    "R"
    ],
    "sortingScore":44.03
    },
```

I want to sort this using the Sortingscoring which is one of the fields within docs. The whole chunks(in this case there are two) within docs should be sorted.So after sorting the final json should be like below.  I have referred to few of the stackoverflow links
[sort json object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript)
but not able to get it.

```
{
"statusCode":200,
"body":{
"docs":[
{
"Scoring":2.029842275,
"_text_":[
],
"id":"customer_channel_analytics_bang.pdf",
"jac_Score":0.09041591320072333,
"matchScore":0.6875,
"scaledTf_idf":0.0,
"searchTerm":[
"Machine learning",
"Deep learning",
"Sas",
"R"
],
"sortingScore":44.03
},
{
"Scoring":1.68466776,
"_text_":[
],
"id":"health_analytics.pdf",
"jac_Score":0.07370184254606366,
"matchScore":0.65,
"scaledTf_idf":0.0,
"searchTerm":[
"Machine learning",
"Deep learning",
"R",
"Python",
"Sas"
],
"sortingScore":59.78
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: Potential duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/q/881510/7475279

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JSON by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/sorting-json-by-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = `{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "Scoring": 2.029842275,
        "_text_": [],
        "id": "customer_channel_analytics_bang.pdf",
        "jac_Score": 0.09041591320072333,
        "matchScore": 0.6875,
        "scaledTf_idf": 0,
        "searchTerm": [
          "Machine learning",
          "Deep learning",
          "Sas",
          "R"
        ],
        "sortingScore": 64.03
      },
      {
        "Scoring": 1.68466776,
        "_text_": [],
        "id": "health_analytics.pdf",
        "jac_Score": 0.07370184254606366,
        "matchScore": 0.65,
        "scaledTf_idf": 0,
        "searchTerm": [
          "Machine learning",
          "Deep learning",
          "R",
          "Python",
          "Sas"
        ],
        "sortingScore": 59.78
      },
      {
        "Scoring": 3.029842275,
        "_text_": [],
        "id": "sex_anal_lyctics.pdf",
        "jac_Score": 0.09041591320072333,
        "matchScore": 0.6875,
        "scaledTf_idf": 0,
        "searchTerm": [
          "Machine learning",
          "Deep learning",
          "Sas",
          "R"
        ],
        "sortingScore": 14.03
      }
    ]
  }
}`;



var obj = JSON.parse(json);

for(var i = 0; i < obj.body.docs.length; i++){
  obj.body.docs.forEach(function(value,index){
    var counter = index;
    var temp;
    if(index < obj.body.docs.length-1){
      if(obj.body.docs[index].sortingScore > obj.body.docs[counter+1].sortingScore){
          temp = obj.body.docs[index];
          obj.body.docs[index] = obj.body.docs[counter+1];
          obj.body.docs[counter+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  });
}

console.log(obj.body.docs);
```

// hi there this is a sequential one i don't recommend if data is huge and just change comparison to > or < to suit your sort preference

[View In Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y19tb7dL/)

Comment: Hi Nyuu. I am using a tool which accepts javascript. When i put this code there i am getting syntax error. I believe the $.each which is jquery is not accepted by the tool. can you please change it to javascript. that would be very helpful.

Comment: actually (value,index) is javascript  | 
jquery is (index,value) sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var a = {
      "Scoring":2.029842275,
      "_text_":[
      ],
      "id":"customer_channel_analytics_bang.pdf",
      "jac_Score":0.09041591320072333,
      "matchScore":0.6875,
      "scaledTf_idf":0.0,
      "searchTerm":[
      "Machine learning",
      "Deep learning",
      "Sas",
      "R"
      ],
      "sortingScore":44.03
  }
var b = {
      "Scoring":1.68466776,
      "_text_":[
      ],
      "id":"health_analytics.pdf",
      "jac_Score":0.07370184254606366,
      "matchScore":0.65,
      "scaledTf_idf":0.0,
      "searchTerm":[
      "Machine learning",
      "Deep learning",
      "R",
      "Python",
      "Sas"
      ],
      "sortingScore":59.78
}
var c = [ {a},{b}]
console.log(a.id)
console.log(b.id)
console.log(c.sort(function(a, b){
    return a - b;
}));
```

Comment: sorting should be based on the field "sortingScore"

Comment: update sorting function to - return a.sortingScore - b.sortingScore;