# How to sort object by key date?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
   var obj = {
  "2019-01-28 00:00:00.000": [],
  "2019-01-29 00:00:00.000": [],
  "2019-01-30 00:00:00.000": [],
  "2019-02-02 00:00:00.000": []
}
```

How sort this object by key/date?

I tried iterate all element and convert to `new Date(element)` then compare with prev value.

Comment: Order of keys in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795)

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685499/9368703)?

Comment: This works when you know name of property, my case is different

Comment: You would have to split this object into a sorted array of objects for it to work properly.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528472/9368703) will work then

Comment: You don’t need to convert into Date instances here, these values are sortable using simple string comparison already.

Comment: @adiga actually, it's been a while the order is guaranteed: http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object and you can rely on that (but I would strongly suggest to use `Map` if the order is mandatory).

Comment: @adiga as said, better use `Map` IMVHO, however, the order is predictable and the OP doesn't actually deal with "numerical keys" – they're string, and "a String property name `P` is an array index if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to `P` and `ToUint32(P)` is not equal to `2^32-1`", and definitely this is not the case of the OP.

Comment: @ZER0 In that case [the mdn documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties) need to be updated.

Comment: @HMR definitely! Although the `for…in` and `Reflect.enumerate` is different from `Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Reflect.ownKeys`; the order is still defined.

Comment: @ZER0 yes, I should've read [this section](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#integer-indices) more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of keys is not fixed in javascript. You could extract the keys, sort the keys and then run a function for each key

```
var objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
objKeys.sort();
objKeys.forEach( (value) => {
    // do something with obj[value]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var keys= Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b){
    // Probably you cast the Date applying a new Date()
    // Also you can use > to order DESC
    // You can create a function to order ASC or DESC
    return a<b;
});

// Now you could iterate your object ordered
keys.foreach(function(k) {
    // This your fist element ordered obj[k]
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort