# How to make a Leaderboard using objects inside objects? Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so I am trying to make a leaderboard of the players with more points, the object kinda looks like this:

```
let currency = {
    person1: {
        money: 1004,
        level: 20
    },
    person2: {
        money: 124,
        level: 3
    },
    person3: {
        money: 50144,
        level: 102
    }
}
```

and what I want to do is it to create a leaderboard based on everyone's MONEY (not level)
For example:

1. person3 | 50144
2. person1 | 1004
3. person2 | 124

Any help will be appreciated since i have been stuck in this part.

Comment: Too bad it's not an array of objects, then it'd be a trivial property-based sort. (That's a hint :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort json object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating over your object using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), then you can filter the output array with [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and finally just [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to get your desired format.

```js
const currency = {
  person1: {
    money: 1004,
    level: 20,
  },
  person2: {
    money: 124,
    level: 3,
  },
  person3: {
    money: 50144,
    level: 102,
  },
};

const result = Object.entries(currency)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1].money - a[1].money)
  .map((p) => `${p[0]} | ${p[1].money}`);

console.log(result);
```